How can I fix this issue with threads in cpp
I am trying to make functions run while one is spleeping and I have found thread but whenever i do something with it it's showing me errors.
Here is some of code, I think it's only thing that is necessary.
std::thread t1(&updatePoints);
t1.join();

void Game::updatePoints()
{
    if (ButtonPressedTimes > 0) {
        
        this->points += this->ButtonPressedTimes;
        std::cout << "You have " << points << " points \n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        
    }
}

When I'm running this code, I'm getting error mesage on the bottom
'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
I tried getting rid of reference by simply deleting & but it's not working and it only gave me another error which told me to add & .I also tried adding agrument just so it would be there.

As a guess (since you don't show us a proper [mre] or the actual errors you get), updatePoints is a non-static member function of Game. That means you need to pass an object for the function to be called on.

Is Game::updatePoints a static or a non-static member of Game? If it's a non-static one, then (obviously?) you can't just call it out of the blue -- you need an object to call it on, which changes the thread construction because you have to provide that object.

Game::updatePoints is non-static I use it to add points to counter

@wodnulec_003 and what would be the instance of that class that your thread should be working on? Is it a global variable? A member variable of whatever class your thread stuff is actually happening? These thread lines just float around in nowhere space...

To prevent guesses, please always post complete code.
